# Getting wrong answer in codechef (The Lead Game)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

The first line of the input will contain a single integer N (N ≤ 10000) indicating the number of rounds in the game. Once all the rounds are over the player who had the maximum lead at the end of any round in the game is declared the winner.Your output must consist of a single line containing two integers W and L, where W is 1 or 2 and indicates the winner and L is the maximum lead attained by the winner.
When I am submitting this answer in codechef, I get Wrong Answer. I don't know why. Can anyone help me out in finding out what's wrong with my code?
Example

Input:

```
5
140 82
89 134
90 110
112 106
88 90
Output:

1 58
```

```
testcases = int(input())
lead = 0
for i in range(testcases):
    player1,player2 = map(int,input().split())
    if abs(player1 - player2) >= abs(lead):
        lead = player1-player2
        if lead>0:
            w = 1
        else:
            w = 2
print(w,abs(lead))
```

Comment: Can you also add an example of input ?

Comment: Explain a bit more about how the output should be appeared in the assertion as well as what it was returned as an error.

Answer (score 1):

In "The Lead Game" every Lead is Determined by the cumulative difference of score but here you finding the lead with every new score, which is wrong.

Use this code:

```
testcases = int(input())

#cumulative score for player 1 and 2
c1=0
c2=0
max_lead=0

for i in range(testcases):
    player1,player2 = map(int,input().split())
    
    # determine the cumulative score
    c1+=player1
    c2+=player2
    
    if c1>c2:
        lead = c1-c2
        if lead > max_lead:
            max_lead = lead
            w=1
    else:
        lead = c2-c1
        if lead > max_lead:
            max_lead = lead
            w=2
              
print(w,max_lead)
```